# How to make a rig like curve handle with control points

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints, drivers

With curves, you get good control points that move with the middle handle. I'd like to do that with bones but I'm experiencing problems with dependency cycles.
How am I supposed to do that?

i want to make this:
[image]

but with these:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best solution.
so I used 3 armatures
-first we need to uncheck lock object mode so we can select our bones from different armatures
[image]
-then parent two control points to the main one
[image]
-then using **object constraint** not bone one
copy reversed location of other control point bone from other object
and set offset to true so we can have some initial distance from middle bone (in object mode) like set first armature 1 unit ahead middle and second armature 1 unit behind middle
[image]
and very important part that makes all this work:
setting target to **pose space** and owner to **world** so there will be no dependency
but if we translate middle bone because both of controls are moving there will be dependency and glitching
also rotating middle bone because of setting owner to world break it
here is my results:
[image]

So please let me know if you come up with another idea.